# 403 forbidden error occurred while testing Rest client API on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, postman

403 forbidden error occurred while testing Rest client API on Jmeter , the same API works fine on Postman.What could be the difference between Jmeter and Postman calls?
There is no trace on server logs for the call from Jmeter, whereas when I run the test on Postman, we can see the entry in server.

Comment: Same exact headers? can you give all/part of what you are sending?

Comment: yes, same headers. Passing access_token,clientid and clienttype.

Comment: Have you check https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27493/getting-error-403-in-jmeter

Comment: We are using Identity service and its a https call.
Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute request in Postman it shouldn't be a problem to record it in JMeter.

1. Prepare JMeter for recording

   - The fastest and the easiest way to configure JMeter for recording is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature. From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Template -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder): Expand `Workbench`, choose `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Prepare Postman for recording.

   - You need to c[onfigure Postman to use JMeter as a proxy](http://blog.eviltester.com/2016/12/how-to-configure-postman-native-client.html). Postman respects  `--proxy-server` argument where you can specify proxy host and port

     ```
     C:\Users\your_username_here\AppData\Local\Postman\app-x.x.x\Postman.exe --proxy-server=localhost:8888
     ```
3. Now if you execute a request in Postman JMeter will record it and convert into the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to follow the steps but got 'ip helper library getipaddrtable function failed' error. Could not proceed.